# router not learning the default route announced by RIPv2 if the same route exists via a better path

Tags: routing, juniper-junos, rip

Let's say, that one has a following simple network topology:

```
r1 ◄ ► r3

▲      ▲
▼      ▼

r2 ◄ ► r4
```

All four routers speak RIPv2 on all interfaces. `r1` and `r2` announce the default route which means that `r4` receives the default route from `r3`(it learned it from `r1` via RIP) and `r2`. For example, here is the packet capture from interface of `r4` facing the `r3`:

```
18:20:23.759926 02:06:dd:04:ff:f1 > 01:00:5e:00:00:09, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 326: (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 50254, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 312)
    10.10.129.1.520 > 224.0.0.9.520: [udp sum ok] 
        RIPv2, Response, length: 284, routes: 14 or less
          Auth header: Packet Len 264, Key-ID 1, Auth Data Len 20, SeqNo 1591543212, MBZ 0, MBZ 0
          AFI IPv4,       200.0.1.0/24, tag 0x0000, metric: 3, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,        10.5.5.0/24, tag 0x0000, metric: 1, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,     10.10.128.1/32, tag 0x0000, metric: 1, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,     192.168.1.0/30, tag 0x0000, metric: 1, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,     192.168.3.0/24, tag 0x0000, metric: 1, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,         0.0.0.0/0 , tag 0x0064, metric: 2, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,      10.1.254.0/24, tag 0x0000, metric: 2, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,   10.10.128.100/32, tag 0x0000, metric: 2, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,   10.10.128.200/32, tag 0x0000, metric: 3, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,       100.0.0.0/24, tag 0x0000, metric: 2, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,     200.0.100.0/24, tag 0x0000, metric: 4, next-hop: self
          AFI IPv4,     200.0.200.0/24, tag 0x0000, metric: 5, next-hop: self
          Auth trailer:
          0x0000:  b144 2983 094a 463d f34f 96d3 77e3 9809
```

As seen above, the `r3` indeed announces the default route. However, it is not seen from the `r4`:

```
root@r4> show route receive-protocol rip 10.10.129.1 0.0.0.0      

inet.0: 20 destinations, 21 routes (20 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)

root@r4>
```

I understand that `r4` prefers the default route via `r2` as it has the lower hop count, but why isn't the default route announced by `r3` seen the the output of `show route receive-protocol rip` or as a non-active route in the output of `show route protocol rip` in `r4`?

Comment: Because RIP is a simple protocol. If the route it uses fails, then it must wait for the next update period until it can replace it. That is why other routing protocols are preferred, and RIP is rarely used.

Comment: What do you mean by if the route it uses fails? Does RIP work in a way that there can't be multiple routes to the same prefix? So in my example, there is already a route to `0.0.0.0/0` via `r2 <-> r4` path and thus RIP can't install another `0.0.0.0/0` prefix via `r1 <-> r3 <-> r4` path to `r4`?

Comment: "_Does RIP work in a way that there can't be multiple routes to the same prefix?_" Exactly. RIP is a simple routing protocol. It was not even until RIPv2 that it got triggered updates. RIP was created before there was a separate RIB and FIB.